# How would I prototype a 400 MHz Colpitts oscillator?

Tags: rf

I previously posted about the practicality of designing an oscillator on a breadboard and got a few different responses that more or less said the same thing - it can't be done on a breadboard. As of the closing of the question, I maxed out the performance at ~9.7 MHz. I unfortunately don't have nH inductors but after decreasing the capacitors below 0.1 nF, the circuit no longer oscillated.

I want to make a Colpitts oscillator that is 400+ MHz but don't know how I would go about prototyping such a design. I have not seen answers online of people going this high in frequency. Can I please get some advice? Let me know what additional details you need.

Edit:
I put a 4.7uH inductor in parallel with another unknown (probably low uH from network analyzer deduction) and got ~12 MHz. It seems decreasing the inductor becomes necessary past once capacitors are smaller than 1nF.

Comment: Don't use a board, just solder the few parts directly together.

Comment: maybe the original breadboard ... https://tangentsoft.com/elec/breadboard.html

Comment: You have nH inductors as long as you got any wire laying around. [Example](https://wcalc.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/air_coil.cgi?wc_unit_menu_3_0=GHz&N=4&dia=0.25&wc_unit_menu_1_0=inch&len=0.182045&wc_unit_menu_0_0=inch&use_fill=yes&fill=1.69523&AWG=22&rho=3e-08&wc_unit_menu_4_0=Ohm&wc_unit_menu_4_1=m&freq=400&wc_unit_menu_5_0=MHz&analyze=Analyze&L=100&wc_unit_menu_2_0=nH)

Comment: [Start here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZSS2ajxhiQBXX-hLFPNWD_GAECi6BOZC), go to the associated EEVblog forum post, there's so much stuff there you'll be reading for a day or two :) Good luck!

Comment: Of course there is a difference between a practical oscillator and one that works only until you touch it. In an oscillator like that, parasitics are a part of the circuit. So you can't just assemble it on the breadboard, move it to a PCB, and expect it to be tuned anywhere close to the one on the breadboard, even if the components are identical. But yes, it will work on the breadboard, no problem. 400MHz is easy for a breadboard. There's enough parasitics on a solderless breadboard to make an oscillator using nothing but the inductances and capacitances of the metal connecting strips.

Comment: Every 1cm of 1mm wire has about 6nH of inductance. https://www.eeweb.com/tools/wire-self-inductance-calculator/

Answer (score 1):

You can do dead-bug construction that uses copper tape for ground and perhaps islands for the component leads. You can also use single sided copper clad PCB and remove copper with a hobby knife to create islands. Do an Internet search for "dead bug breadboard" and you'll get ideas of how people did their dead bug prototypes.

A [link](https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?t=27494) honoring Jim Williams dead bug projects.

The following image is a prototype for a project I did about 30 years ago showing the top & bottom of the board. Wire wrap was used for the interconnections. This probably operated around 4 MHz.

[image]